# Mysterious Changing Javascript Variable

Tags: php, javascript, variables, global

I have the following hunk of JS where I define `var i` with some PHP.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var i = <?php echo $photo_count; ?>;
    function updatePreview(){
        var x = document.getElementById('preimage').value;
        var y = document.getElementById('precapt').value;
        var preview = "";
        var special = document.getElementById('special').value;

        i++;
        preview += "<div id='smallbox"+i+"' class='smallbox'><table><tr><td rowspan='2'><img id='picture"+i+"' src='"+x+"' /><br /><input type='button' onclick='removeimg("+i+");' value='delete' /></td><td>URL: <input onchange='updateimg("+i+");' type='text' id='image"+i+"' value='"+x+"'/></td></tr><tr><td>Caption: <input type='text' id='capt"+i+"' value='"+y+"'/></td></tr></table></div><hr />";
        //window.alert(preview);



        //document.getElementById('special').value += "#"+x+"|"+y;
        document.getElementById('preview').innerHTML += preview;
        document.getElementById('preimage').value = "";
        document.getElementById('precapt').value = "";
        //window.alert(document.getElementById('special').value);
    }

    function showSubmit(){
        window.alert("i = "+i);
        document.getElementById('hideImg').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('hideTags').style.display = "block";
        while(i>1){
            var img = document.getElementById("image"+i).value;
            var capt = document.getElementById("capt"+i).value;
            if(img.length>3){
                document.getElementById('special').value += "#"+img+"|"+capt;
                window.alert(document.getElementById('special').value);
                window.alert("i = "+i);
                document.getElementById('preview2').innerHTML += "<img class='postpreviewimg' src='"+img+"' />";
            }
            i--;
        }
        document.getElementById('preview').style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
```

In the page's source I can see that PHP is defining `i` correctly but in the first line of `showSubmit()` where I `alert(i)` it shows `i`'s value to be `1`, unless `updatePreview()` is called first.

In other words.. if the pages source looks like this: `var i = 36;` and then I call the function `showSubmit()` it alerts `i = 1` when it should alert `i = 36`

Each time `updatePreview()` is called `i` will increment from 1, instead of from 36.

Am I defining `i` incorrectly? Isn't that the proper way to set a global variable?

Comment: try alert i on start of updatePreview

Comment: can you look for `i` value in a console?

Comment: Use `console.log(i);` throughout the script and have a closer look in the `developer view` in Google chrome. I am sure you will find what you are looking for :)

Comment: everything is ok wtih your code. I have tryed on my website i when I call first  showSubmit(); it alerts me 36

Comment: @CroiOS I get the same thing at the begining of `updatePreview()` `i = 1`

Comment: If you add `showSubmit()` just before `</script>` it would also alert the correct value. It changes in another script on the page. What else are you including?

Comment: This is killing me, there's an `$i` (php) but that's literally the only JavaScript on the entire page. Nothing is showing up in the console.

Comment: @Adelphia - please put whole page source (html) somewhere and show us lik so we can take a look.

Comment: @CroiOS http://syncopemedia.com/source.txt

Comment: As you can see in this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8jfJc/ your code works. There must be more javascript included on the page. Or another possibility> dont use FF when requesting the source. Firefox reloads the page to show the source. So its possible that the page you see is different then the source you request

Comment: For a page literally not having any other source code, it sure looks like `scripts/nicEdit.js` is included and contains code.

Comment: Okay, maybe I should clarify, that's literally the only JS on the page which uses `i`. I hand typed every line of this in Notepad++ (except the nicEdit stuff). This is an adaptation of another script which posts content to a database for an image gallery. I'm adapting it to EDIT the image gallery content. The nicEdit.js didn't interfere on that page, there no reason for it to interfere on this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are defining `i` as a global variable. So every script on the page that uses something like `i=10` will change this value.

And since `i` is a common used variable counter name its very likely there is a script that changes it. If you use `var MyPhotoCount = <?php echo $photo_count; ?>;` as name its more likely to work.

Even if this other script is included before or after this script it could cause problems. The other script could be using an `on ready function` or any other delay that is triggered before you call `ShowSubmit();`

Global variables should always be unique. And you also just found the reason why its never a good idea to use them. You cannot trust their value.

UPDATE:

You are including nicEdit.js on your page and that script contains the following code (line 185 in full source):

```
domLoaded : function() {
    if (arguments.callee.done) return;
    arguments.callee.done = true;
    for (i = 0;i < bkLib.domLoad.length;i++) bkLib.domLoad[i]();
},
```

Your i variable is changed there.

Comment: So solution is to change variable nname from "i" to "myCustomI" :)

Comment: or `MyPhotoCount` or even change nicEdit.js to use `for (var i = ...` as it should

Comment: whaaa... i have that script on the original, working version of the one i'm editing now and it is not affecting it there... thanks for pointing that out +1